# How to execute a function right before a form is submitted

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Let's say I have:

```
<form action="myurl.com" method="post" id="myForm">
    <input type="number" name="number" class="numberInput">
    <input type="number" name="number">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And a javascript function that I want executed right before form submission:

```
function executeBeforeSubmission(){
    var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
    var inputs = form.getElementsByClassName("numberInput");
    for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
        inputs[i].name = "number"+i;
    }
}
```

How can I assign this method to be executed right before form submission?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following jQuery code to perform any actions before the form is submitted:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    // Stuff to do. In your case call the function.
    executeBeforeSubmission();
    return true; // return false to cancel form action
});
```